# Google cloud storage Rate limit error - why?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm have a problem with google cloud storage and gsutil when use -m option on file uploading. I want to upload ~400 files in multi thread mode (using -m option), but get errors: AccessDeniedException: 403 Rate limit exceeded. Please retry this request later.

This command i use:

```
gsutil -m -q rsync -R -c -d -e mydir gs://mybucket/mydir1/mydir
```

I'm using this from gce instance but from custom service account user which has a next access scopes: Editor; Storage Admin; Storage Object Admin; Storage Object Creator and it owner of bucket.

If I upload files without -m it work nice. In google docs I can't found anything about limits.

Please help with understanding this situation, thx!

Comment: Would you mind emailing gs-team@google.com with your project ID and a gsutil -D -m rsync ... debug log of the problem?

Comment: No, I think maybe this is a typical error or I can't find an answer in documentation or in interface